# AS3 - Understanding how [Embed] metadata works

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, embed, loading, sprite-sheet

While developing a game I usually load my assets using a loader, while listening to whenever the loading is completed before even interaction with each object I'm loading.

However, I found people are using the Embed in order to "load" images and sprite sheets, in order to improve performance and so on. So I did, but I do not understand how it's actually work in real-time. My game is running on the web, and how could I know for sure the Embedded image are loaded and ready to use? I understand it's loaded when compiling the project while running on local, but what will happen when running on the web or on mobile?

I'm doing something like this:

```
public final class Assests 
{
    [Embed(source="../assets/character.png")]
    public var Character:Class;
    public var characterBMD:BitmapData = new Character().bitmapData;
}
```

What if there are tones of graphics to load? How can I listen to whenever it's ready, while showing the user a loading screen, just as usually via the loader Class.

Comment: Embed, as the name suggests, embeds the asset in the swf.  So no loading is required as it's loaded in with everything else in the swf. (just like library assets in FlashPro)

Comment: I understand, but I cannot see it's affect my main SWF file size. Is there a way to see it clearly?

Comment: It should impact size. You can use a swf explorer and see all the assets embedded.

Comment: if you had many assets, I'd probably use a sprite sheet or create an swc library to embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Embed`, as the name suggests, embeds the asset inside the swf file itself. So no loading is required as it's loaded as part of the swf file (along with code and any other assets embedded in the swf).   This is the equivalent of having library assets in Flash Professional.     All your assets are a part of the SWF file.

Using a `Loader`, is loading in a separate asset after the swf file has loaded.

So, embedding will add to the size of the swf (and cause the entire swf to load slower).

Loading with `Loader` after the fact, makes the initial swf open quicker, and then allows you to load asynchronously and show a progress bar or do other things during the load.   It also allows you to have dynamically loaded content. So you can do things like determine the users screen resolution, and load a higher-resolution images for that user if their system would benefit from that.

Generally, loading with a Loader is best for large files.  Embedding is great for lots of little files or anything you need available immediately.

Comment: I guess it's mean I cannot do generic embedding such as this: [Embed(source="../assets/"+NAME+"/Character.png")]

Comment: You could with compiler constants I think, though I've never tried it.

Comment: What is your IDE?  Flex? FlashDevelop? something else?    And how do you determine what `Name` is?

Comment: FlashDevelop. Name is a directory name for example, determine by Main class.

Comment: In FlashDevelop, goto your project properties, then the 'Compiler Options' tab.  You'll find in the list a "Compiler Constants" array, where you can put in constants for compile time.  eg. `CONFIG::directoryName,myDirectory`.   Then in your code anywhere you reference `CONFIG::directoryName` will be replaced with your constant when you compile.   Just remember that they are constants, so naturally you can't change it in any classes, only in the project properties of FlashDevelop.          http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3_Conditional_Compilation

Comment: The Main class should transfer the assets class which directory it should load, because I'm getting this data from outside (server). Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible to write pre-compiler scripts in FlashDevelop to update the constant based your server, but I've never done that before.   Sounds like though that you actually need these assets to load at runtime.  If different end users need different directories, then it will have to be runtime loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `[Embed]` it's compiling the assets into the SWF, so there's no additional loading at runtime. By the time your AS3 is executing, the asset is ready to be used.

This speeds up initial load time because loading in assets has a lot of overhead [relatively speaking] that can be skipped when its embedded directly in the SWF, however the trade-off is that the SWF itself becomes much heavier and you have no choice but to load the embedded assets with the SWF.